# How to show tooltip for longer time in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++, user-interface, tooltip, c++builder, vcl

I have a tooltip shown to an Image

```
ImageIcon->Hint = "This is a long tooltip I need some more time to read it";
```

I want to increase the showing time of this tooltip.

Please, Anyone can help me regarding this?

Comment: Do you want to expand all hint times in you application, or only for your ImageIcon control?

Comment: Valid question, by the way (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may handle the `OnShowHint` event of your `Application` object. When this event handler is called, change the `HideTimeout` attribute of the `HintInfo` parameter. The value can been chosen depending on the hint's length and the control that the hint is being prepared for. I found this approach more appropriate than increasing the [`HintHidePause` property](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_HintHidePause.html) of `TApplication`, because hints can vary heavily in length, and very short hints can also be very annoying when shown for too long time.

For reference, start reading the following article:

- [TApplication.OnShowHint Event](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_OnShowHint.html)

Comment: Hi Wolf . . . I implemented using your answer it works like a charm. . . Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use `HintHidePause` to specify a wait time in milliseconds for the entire application.

E.g. to change the default value of 2500ms (2.5s) to 30 seconds:

```
Application->HintHidePause = 30000;
```

If you only need to change the delay for the `ImageIcon` control, something like this should work:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::DoShowHint(UnicodeString &HintStr, bool &CanShow, THintInfo &HintInfo)
{
  // By default, it's set to the value of the Application variable's
  // HintHidePause property
  if (HintInfo.HintControl == ImageIcon)
    HintInfo.HideTimeout = 30000;
}
```

Comment: ...it's not so easy to convince Anup this time. Anyway, thanks for the refreshing (indirect) discussion. ;)

Comment: @Wolf HintHidePause is convenient (just one line), but you're right... not very flexible.

Comment: +1 for the copy-paste friendly version. Sometimes it's better to be fast :) whereas often not in the long term...

Comment: Now we just need to convince Embarcadero to do this for Hints in the Watch window